# Show that $3$ distinct points $(p, p^2), (q, q^2)$ and $(r, r^2)$ can never be collinear, using the triangle formula.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Show that $3$ distinct points $(p, p^2), (q, q^2)$ and $(r, r^2)$ can never be collinear, using the triangle formula.

I tried doing it using 
$$\text{Area }= \frac{1}{2}\big| (x_1y_2 + x_2y_3 + x_3y_1) - (x_2y_1 + x_3y_2 + x_1y_3) \big|$$ 
and equating it to zero. But I can’t. Plz help.

Comment: The area formula factors very nicely. Give it a try! ... In any case, you should show what you got for that formula, so that someone can advise you on next steps or possibly identify an error. (Generally, the more effort you show, the more likely you'll be to get an answer. Conversely, little-to-no effort often results in down- and close-votes. The community here likes to be assured that they aren't simply being asked to do your homework for you.)

Comment: Thank you, Blue. I have indeed tried a lot and reached this.

Comment: 1/2 | pq^2 + qr^2 + rp^2 - qp^2 - rq^2 - pr^2 |

Comment: However I have no idea how to proceed!

Comment: The polynomial $pq^2+qr^2+rp^2-qp^2-rq^2-pr^2$ vanishes when $p=q$, or when $q=r$, or when $r=p$ (when two points coincide, the area is $0$).  What does this say about the factorization of this polynomial?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool that's really clever! You should consider posting it as an answer

Comment: @pooja  J.G. already did the job, saving me a bit of time. :D

Comment: Haha, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If factoring area formula seems hard, equivalently, you may row reduce the determinant and show the product along diagonal is never zero:
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&p&p^2\\1&q&q^2\\1&r&r^2 \end{vmatrix}\ne 0$$
when $p,q,r$ are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

The area is $$\frac12|pq^2+qr^2+rp^2-qp^2-rq^2-pr^2|=\frac12|(p-q)(q-r)(r-p)|.$$You can guess this factorisation by realising the points *will* be collinear if any two of $p,\,q,\,r$ are equal, in which case the area will be $0$. But otherwise, the area is clearly non-zero as required.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the area formula of the form below
$$
A= \frac12 \big| (x_1 - x_3) (y_2 - y_1) - (x_1 - x_2) (y_3 - y_1) \big|
$$
$$
=\frac12\big| (p-r)(q^2-p^2)-(p-q)(r^2-p^2)\big|$$
$$=\frac12 \big| (p-r)(q-p)(r-q)\big|\ne 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really helpful.

Comment: @Dora - No problem.